# Loading custom pages with get_template_part()

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I came across this function the get_template_part  by talk to other person about what easy why to load custom page on front-end page he told me the  get_template_part  and i think its awesome for reuse of code. But him use it to loaded all my custom pages on front-page but when I view the site some content loads and some does not load on the site here screenshot.

[image]

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front-Page
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/header'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/page-about'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/page-services'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/page-photography'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/page-portfolio'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/page-contact'); ?>
                <?php get_template_part('templates/footer'); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely either in the template files themselves, you're missing the template files, or your file names don't match your function call. For example to show your About page this code

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/page-about'); ?>
```

Means you should have a directory in your theme folder named 'templates' and a file in that directory called page-about.php. If all your files are present and correctly named you need to look in the template files themselves and check the code there

Comment: Everything is in the same directory and everything in side the right folders https://gyazo.com/4e86a0cabf25bfb6cbd398828836112d I ready have all the file names made up just want know what not show up

Comment: If everything's in the right place and correctly named and some of the template parts work you need to look inside the template files.

Comment: Don't know what you mean could you explain more better you trying to tell me what to do because looking at templates parts what him opposed to look for

Comment: If your template parts aren't showing any data then someone needs to open the about-page.php (for example - or which ever file is not displaying data) file and look at the code there. If someone built this for you that's really who you should  be talking to.

Comment: I'm learn wordpress and working on small project so I can started build more wordpress site for people.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional info you've posted on Linkedin, about the site being a one-page website, your problem is most likely because you're using the wrong file to load the homepage.

**To solve this, do the following in the theme's folder:**

1. Create a file called "home.php"
2. Move the contents of "page-home.php" to "home.php"
3. Remove the while loop so that home.php will look like this:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
      
      <?php get_template_part('templates/header'); ?>
      <?php get_template_part('templates/page-about'); ?>
      <?php get_template_part('templates/page-services'); ?>
      <?php get_template_part('templates/page-photography'); ?>
      <?php get_template_part('templates/page-portfolio'); ?>
      <?php get_template_part('templates/page-contact'); ?>
      <?php get_template_part('templates/footer'); ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: @Atemus The other problem is the some the content like the featured image not show up on the home.php I did everything what you told me to do.